# Cannot find the error in C++ code

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there anything wrong with this code? This is a part of function for reading database data. `o` is `otl_stream` object for database output stream. My mentor told me that I have mistake in this code, I am newbie to C++ and can't figure out what is problem... I must use pointers, so please don't tell me to use static char array.

```
char* temp_char;

while (!o.eof()) {

   temp_char = new char [31];
   o>>temp_char;

   records.push_back(temp_char);

   delete[] temp_char;

}
```

Comment: `while (!o.eof())`, is wrong, and `delete[] temp_char;` (unless `records.push_back(temp_char)` copies the pointee).

Comment: @DanielFischer Why? Explain, please.

Comment: @antimatter is this ultimately to read strings from an input stream, separated by whitespace, and store them into the `records` collection?

Comment: @antimatter : What type is `records`? Why would you think this question is answerable without that information?

Comment: @ildjarn sorry, vector is type of std::string

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 2):

`o.eof()` only becomes true after you tried to read past the end of the stream, so you shouldn't use `while(!o.eof())` for the loop control.

Unless `recods.push_back(temp_char)` copies the pointed-to array, `records` will contain a dangling pointer after `delete[] temp_char;`

```
while(true) {
    temp_char = new char[31];
    o >> temp_char;
    if (!o) {
        delete[] temp_char;
        break;
    }
    records.push_back(temp_char);
}
```

looks better (although I'm sure it's not idiomatic).

Of course, using `std::string` would relieve you of the memory management.

Comment: +1, or better still, seriously consider why you're *not* using `std::string` both here and in your `records` collection.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer records is vector<string> so it copies temp_char to string, right? and then deletes temp_char...

Comment: @antimatter Okay, in that case, the "unless" would apply. The `o.eof()` part stays, however.

Comment: !o.eof() is okay, because while loop must iterate through all stream in object o, until the end. So, there is nothing wrong with this code?

Comment: @antimatter No, at the end of the stream, you would attempt another extraction which would fail, since there is no more input, and you'd `push_back` a `char*` with indeterminate contents. If there is no 0-byte in the allocated block, the string constructor would read out of bounds.

Comment: @DanielFischer That will not happen, because when stream comes to the end, while loop will break.

Comment: @antimatter So it's a custom self-implemented stream class, and not a `std::ifstream` or such?

Comment: @antimatter Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for `eof()`.

Comment: @DanielFischer that's stream class from OTL_stream object, for connecting to the database (see: otl.sourceforge.net). I wrote a few similar functions like this, before, and never had problems with otl_stream. Saw !o.eof() in Examples section on official webpage.

Comment: @antimatter The docs say: "This function has the same meaning as the eof() function in C++ streams". If that's wrong, your use of `!o.eof()` could be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reallocate the string each time I read a word.
And if the last iteration reads spaces, an empty string will be pushed back.

```
    char* temp_char = new char[BUF_SZ];

    while ( ! o.eof() ) {

       o>>temp_char;
if( *temp_char != '\0' ) // If not an empty string
       records.push_back(temp_char);

    }

    delete[] temp_char;
```